# Speeding up the conditional filling of huge sparse matrices

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I was wondering if there is a way of speeding up (maybe via vectorization?) the conditional filling of huge sparse matrices (e.g. ~ 1e10 x 1e10). Here's the sample code where I have a nested loop, and I fill in a sparse matrix only if a certain condition is met:

```
% We are given the following cell arrays of the same size:
% all_arrays_1
% all_arrays_2
% all_mapping_arrays

N = 1e10; 

% The number of nnz (non-zeros) is unknown until the loop finishes
huge_sparse_matrix = sparse([],[],[],N,N);

n_iterations = numel(all_arrays_1);

for iteration=1:n_iterations

  array_1 = all_arrays_1{iteration};
  array_2 = all_arrays_2{iteration};

  mapping_array = all_mapping_arrays{iteration};

  n_elements_in_array_1 = numel(array_1);
  n_elements_in_array_2 = numel(array_2);

  for element_1 = 1:n_elements_in_array_1

    element_2     = mapping_array(element_1);

    % Sanity check:
    if element_2 <= n_elements_in_array_2
       item_1 = array_1(element_1);
       item_2 = array_2(element_2);      

       huge_sparse_matrix(item_1,item_2) = 1;
    end     
  end   
end
```

I am struggling to vectorize the nested loop. As far as I understand the filling a sparse matrix element by element is very slow when the number of entries to fill is large (~100M). I need to work with a sparse matrix since it has dimensions in the 10,000M x 10,000M range. However, this way of filling a sparse matrix in MATLAB is very slow.

**Edits:**

I have updated the names of the variables to reflect their nature better. There are no function calls.

**Addendum:**

This code builds the matrix adjacency for a huge graph. The variable `all_mapping_arrays` holds mapping arrays (~ adjacency relationship) between nodes of the graph in a **local representation**, which is why I need `array_1` and `array_2` to map the adjacency to a global representation.

Comment: What i think is sparse matrices are good with for loops only.

Comment: You need to provide more info. Is `mapping` a function or a vector/matrix? If it's a function, does it accept a vector input/return a vector output? How big is `n_labels_next`? As @AdityaKumar said, if it's small compared to the matrix dimension, you probably might be better off with a loop than breaking your head over vectorizing.

Comment: Thanks to both! I have updated the variable names to reflect their nature better. Also, there are no function calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it will be the incremental update of the sparse matrix, rather than the loop based conditional that will be slowing things down.

When you add a new entry to a sparse matrix via something like `A(i,j) = 1` it typically requires that the whole matrix data structure is re-packed. The is an expensive operation. If you're interested, MATLAB uses a `CCS` data structure (compressed column storage) internally, which is described under the *Data Structure* section [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/otherdocs/simax.pdf). Note the statement:

> This scheme is not effcient for manipulating matrices one element at a
>   time

Generally, it's far better (faster) to accumulate the non-zero entries in the matrix as a set of triplets and then make a single call to `sparse`. For example (warning - brain compiled code!!):

```
% Inputs:
% N 
% prev_array and  next_array
% n_labels_prev and n_labels_next
% mapping

% allocate space for matrix entries as a set of "triplets"
ii = zeros(N,1);
jj = zeros(N,1);
xx = zeros(N,1);
nn = 0;

for next_label_ix = 1:n_labels_next

    prev_label     = mapping(next_label_ix);

    if prev_label <= n_labels_prev
        prev_global_label = prev_array(prev_label);
        next_global_label = next_array(next_label_ix);   

        % reallocate triplets on demand
        if (nn + 1 > length(ii))
            ii = [ii; zeros(N,1)];
            jj = [jj; zeros(N,1)];
            xx = [xx; zeros(N,1)];
        end   

        % append a new triplet and increment counter
        ii(nn + 1) = next_global_label; % row index
        jj(nn + 1) = prev_global_label; % col index
        xx(nn + 1) = 1.0;               % coefficient
        nn = nn + 1;
    end     
end

% we may have over-alloacted our triplets, so trim the arrays
% based on our final counter
ii = ii(1:nn);
jj = jj(1:nn);
xx = xx(1:nn);

% just make a single call to "sparse" to pack the triplet data
% as a sparse matrix object
sp_graph_adj_global = sparse(ii,jj,xx,N,N);
```

I'm allocating in chunks of `N` entries at a time. Assuming that you know alot about the structure of your matrix you might be able to use a better value here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Darren! I wanted to update the names of the variables to make the code easier to understand. I also realized that there is another loop iterating over the original loop, and have added it to the original code. I really, really appreciate your effort, and will go through your code carefully to see if I can take it from here!

Comment: By the way, I think you are absolutely right about accumulating  triplets first based on some tests I did yesterday!